# Netlogo v6.01: converting map function to anonymous procedures

Tags: dictionary, netlogo, primitive

I'm upgrading a Netlogo model from v5.3.1 to v6.01. In the model, I have a series of lists that I combine/manipulate using the map primitive. I've tried to update the code using the new anonymous procedures, but I can't quite figure it out. I was using the ? syntax, but ? is no longer defined.

Original code:

Parameters:

C, WC-Alpha, A, and Z are all lists

alpha is a constant

set C-alpha map [? ^ (- alpha)] C     ;creates a vector of C^-alpha

set R map [? * (A * Z)] WC-alpha      ;creates R vector

Best,
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [dictionary entry](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) for map? It shows the new syntax, where essentially you define the variable to be used by map. For example, yours might look like:

```
set C-alpha map [ i -> i ^ (- alpha) ] C
```

where you explicitly state that you will be using `i` as the variable for the mapping operation. This allows for more readable code in `map` and other anonymous procedures.

Comment: Thank you, Luke. I had looked in the dictionary, but wasn't coding it correctly. I tested it and it works. Thanks so much.